# NoSuchFileException during upgrade to liferay 6.2 from liferay 5.2.3

Tags: liferay, upgrade, nosuchfileexception

I am trying to migrate to liferay 6.2 from Liferay 5.2.3,first i upgrade to liferay 6.0.6, my database is completely upgraded, but my images and files are not found in version 6.0.6 and I can not find the file.
i use this tutrial o upgrade :
http://msonbati.blogspot.com/2014/12/liferay-migration-form-523-to-62.html

Comment: [Please don't crosspost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site) your question here and elsewhere. And, as a minimum: Link all posts in all directions, so that we see that the question is long answered.

Comment: Also, this particular question is not related to programming, the self-chosen focus of stackoverflow. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. My recommendation: Delete it here, continue on the Liferay forums.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendtion

Comment: How to delete it?

Comment: How to delete it?

Comment: There should be an option somewhere. I can't tell what you see with your permissions on your own question. But AFAIK, as long as there's no answer, there should be some option to delete it. Maybe the region under the question, next to "share" and "edit"?